# Is there a group $G$, for every $n>0$, acts on set $\{1, 2, ..., n^2\}$ with orbit of size $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does there exist a finite group $G$ that, for every $n>0$, has an
>   action on the set $\{1, 2, ..., n^2\}$ with an orbit of size $n$? If yes, construct such a group. Otherwise, explain why not.

$\def\o{\operatorname{Orb}}\def\s{\operatorname{Stab}}$
I think this is true because the *Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem* states that $|\o(x)|=[G:\s(x)]=\frac{|G|}{|\s(x)|}$. And I don't see why we can't have a group $G$ and a set $X$ such that $|\o(x)|=n$, with $\frac{|G|}{|\s(x)|}=\frac{n^2}{n}$. I am not sure how to construct a group where this is true for every $n>0$, however.

Does there in fact exist such a group $G$? If not, why not?

Comment: What a strange question. Are you sure that $G$ is required to be finite?

Comment: @DerekHolt yes $G$ has to be finite. I believe this is true without that constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you want a *single* group $G$ that has actions on $\{1, \ldots, n^2\}$ with orbit size $n$ for *all* $n$. We must have 
$$ |G| \ge [G:\operatorname{Stab}(1)] = |\operatorname{Orb}(1)| = n $$
for all $n$. This contradicts $G$'s finiteness.

Comment: Sorry but how did you get $|G| \ge [G:Stab(1)]$? And how does that expression contradict $G$'s finiteness?

Comment: $[G: Stab(1)]$ is a quotient of $G$, hence smaller then $G$. And no finite number $|G|$ has $|G| \ge n$ for all $n$.